# How do I remove seconds from date time in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

There are several ex for same type but i think this is bit unique.

**My Query is:**

```
select Convert(nvarchar(15),date,103)+ ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20),date, 22), 11))DC from Table1
```

**Result is:**

[image]

I am getting right in the above result. only thing i need to require is the format should  `09/11/2015 2:29 PM`.

there are Many format to achieve this but the user unlike to change any other format.
Thank you in advance

Comment: So what help do you expect from us if you are already aware of many other formats, but your user/customer is not inclined to make changes?

Comment: @Artur Opalinski: In the same format only just remove the seconds part, like `09/11/2015 2:29 PM`.

Comment: You want to return a datetime or a string?

Comment: SQL Server version you are using?

Comment: @shadow: string and  Version is 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, date, 101) + ' ' + left(RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar, date, 100), 7),5) + ' ' +RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar, date, 100), 2)
```

Comment: Almost , can u give a space in between Minutes and PM. above query showing like this `09-11-2015 2:29PM`

Comment: @VikramKumar i have updated the answer

Comment: @jelliaes- Perfect

Comment: This does not seem to work in all cases. Try 9:30 AM and 10:00 AM. The one-digit vs two-digit hours cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try It

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),0),7)DC from Table1
```

Comment: Almost , can u give a space in between Minutes and PM. above query showing like this `09-11-2015 2:29PM`

Comment: SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

Comment: @Shresthamir - `FORMAT` was new in SQL Server 2012. Question is tagged 2008 and 2005.

Comment: sorry i did not knew about SQL Server Version

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, getdate(), 101) + ' ' + RIGHT(replace(replace(CONVERT(nvarchar, getdate(), 100),'PM',' PM'),'AM',' AM'), 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 R2 or newer

```
    select convert( varchar(10), getdate(), 103 )+' '+convert( varchar(5), convert( time, getdate() ) )
-- 25/05/2016 09:58

    select convert( varchar(10), getdate(), 101 )+' '+convert( varchar(5), convert( time, getdate() ) )
-- 05/25/2016 09:59
```

**EDIT**

```
select convert( varchar(10), getdate(), 103 )+' '+right( convert( varchar, getdate(), 100 ), 7 )
-- 25/05/2016 10:13AM

    select convert( varchar(10), getdate(), 101 )+' '+right( convert( varchar, getdate(), 100 ), 7 )
-- 05/25/2016 10:14AM
```

Answer (score 0):

try below sql query. may it will help

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),103)+ ' '+ REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 100), 'P', ' P'), 'A', ' A')
```